# Discriminant not square free and monogenic

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

It is well known that if K is a number field whose discriminant is square free then K is monogenic.

I want to know if the converse is true. If K is monogenic then is the discriminant necessarily square free. In particular the contrapositive, if D is not square free then K is not monogenic.

Is this true?

Comment: Every quadratic field is monogenic but not every quadratic field has square free discriminant, e.g. $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$.

Answer (score 1):

The following converse is not true: "*if $K$ is monogenic then its discriminant is squarefree*". As an example, consider the cubic number field
$$
K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{6}),
$$
which is monogenic with basis $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$ for its ring of integers $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$, where $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{6}$. Its discriminant is given by
\begin{align*}
D(1,\alpha,\alpha^2) & =\det \begin{pmatrix} 
tr (1) & tr (\alpha) & tr (\alpha^2) \\
tr (\alpha) & tr (\alpha ^2) &  tr (\alpha ^3) \\
tr (\alpha ^2) &  tr (\alpha ^3) & tr(\alpha^4)\\
\end{pmatrix} \\[0.2cm]
 & = \det \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 18 \\ 0 & 18 & 0 \end{pmatrix} =-3\cdot 18^2=-972,
\end{align*}

which is not squarefree. So the converse is false.

Comment: So, are there any good necessary conditions for being monogenic?

Comment: There is a collection of criteria [here](http://math.colorado.edu/~hwsmith/monogenicfields.html), which may be useful.